# Joint PDF - Am I understanding this correctly?

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus

The joint PDF for X, Y is:
$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = ce^{-x}e^{-y}\quad 0\leq x \leq 1,\quad y\geq x$
Could someone skim through and check my work to see if I'm understanding what to do correctly?

1. Find c
   Support Area: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHMI0.png)
   $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{\infty}ce^{-x}e^{-y}dydx$
   $\int_{x}^{\infty}ce^{-x}e^{-y}dy=ce^{-2x}$
   $\int_{0}^{1}ce^{-2x} = c[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{e^{-2}}{2}]$
   $c[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{e^{-2}}{2}] = 1$
   $c = ...$
2. E[X]
   $E[X]=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{\infty}cxe^{-x}e^{-y}dydx$
3. E[Y]
   $E[Y]=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{\infty}cye^{-x}e^{-y}dydx$
4. E[X|Y]
   $f_{X|Y}(x) = \frac{f_{x,y}(x,y)}{f_y(y)}$
   $f_Y(y) = \left\{ \begin{aligned} ce^{-y}(1-e^{-y}) &,\quad 0 \le y \le 1 \\ ce^{-y}(1-e^{-1}) &,\quad y > 1 \end{aligned}\right.$
   $f_{x|y}(x) = \left\{ \begin{aligned} \frac{e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-y})} &,\quad 0 \le y \le 1 \\ \frac{e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-1})} &,\quad y > 1 \end{aligned}\right.$
   $E[X|Y] = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-y}}dx + \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-1}}dx$
5. E[Y|X]
   $f_{Y|X}(y) = \frac{f_{x,y}(x,y)}{f_x(x)}$
   $f_X(x) = ce^{-2x}\space\space\space 0\leq x \leq 1$
   $f_{y|x}(y) = \frac{e^{-y}}{e^{-x}} ,\quad 0 \le x \le 1$
   $E[Y|X] = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{ye^{-y}}{e^{-x}}dy$
6. Are X, Y independent?
   If $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_x(x)*f_y(y)$, then yes.
7. Are X, Y uncorrelated?
   Don't know how to do this one.
8. Find correlation coefficient $\rho$
   Don't know how to do this one either.

Comment: 6) "If... then yes". But the condition is not satisfied. This appears if you have a look at the picture of the support. For $x,y\in(0,1)$ we have $f_X(x)>0$ and $f_Y(y)>0$ but not everywhere $f_{X,Y}(x,y)>0$.

Comment: 7) check whether $\mathbb EXY=\mathbb EX\mathbb EY$ (uncorrelated) or not.

Comment: @drhab In this specific case, X & Y are dependent because that requirement is not satisfied. I wrote that as a "conceptual" sort of thing. fx * fy does not equal fxy in this case. I should have been more clear, but for 6 I got not independent.

Comment: Actually you did not answer that question.

Comment: @drhab The correlation of X and Y is E[XY], correct? How would I go about finding that?

Comment: No it is not. The covariance is $\mathbb EXY-\mathbb EX\mathbb EY$ and the [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) is the covariance divided by standard deviations $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$. You can find $\mathbb EXY$ as integral $\int\int xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Btw, I have to go now. Good luck.

Comment: So if E[XY] = E[X]E[Y], then it is uncorrelated.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Good bye now.

Comment: @drhab thank you for your help!